# Change plot axis values dynamically from dataframe in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, rstudio

I'm using Rstudio and Shiny for the project.

I have defined a variable `res` and it contains dataframe with multiple rows and columns, then I make a plot and its x y and color are the data from `res` dataframe.
My problem is that when i Run it, if I write that i want x axis to be inputted variable values (`input$SelInp`), I dont get dataframe values, instead, I get only column name.

if I change the code to get the values directly from dataframe (`res$some_column_name`) I get the correct values.

ui.R

```
selectInput("SelInp",
                         label = "Choose one:",
                         choices = colnames(res)
                         )
```

server.R

```
  output$plt = renderPlot({
                  qplot(data = res,
                     x = input$SelInp, #this only returns a column name 
                     y = res$loan_amnt, # this returns correct values from column loan_amt
                     ylab = "some y axis",
                     xlab = "some x axis",
                     main="Our Chart")
                     }
                     )
```

so, I want to get the values in `input$SelInp` thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason is that the selectInput is returning the column name as a character. qplot is expecting a variable. I didn't check if qplot has an option to use characters to specify scales but aes_string in ggplot does that:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      "selectedCol",
      "Select colum for X axis",
      choices = colnames(mtcars),
      selected = colnames(mtcars)[1]
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot")))
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x_axis <- input$selectedCol
    gg <-
      ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = x_axis, y = "hp", color = "cyl"))
    gg <- gg + geom_point()
    gg
  })
})
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Valter, I managed to recreate plot succesfully using your provided `ggplot` example and it changes dinamycally, as I wanted to, but I still cannot figure out how to do it using `qplot` as my example is

Comment: Glad it helped. I am sure there is a solution with qplot. I'll take a look at it during the week and let you know.